# D Lua doesn't get metatable

Tags: lua, d

I'm trying to get Lua to work with the new programming language D.
Everything works fine (library, lua52.dll, etc.) but `luaL_getmetatable` crashes.
Originally, the function was not defined in *dlua*, but I added it:

```c
    //C     #define luaL_getmetatable(L,n)  (lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, (n)))
    void luaL_getmetatable(lua_State* L, const(char)* s) {
        lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, s);
    }
```

But when I run:

```c
    L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    // prevent script kiddies
    luaL_dostring(L, "os = nil; io = nil");
    // reprogram 'print'
    luaL_newmetatable(L, "vector");
    luaL_getmetatable(L, "vector"); // CRASH
```

it crashes. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: It probably wasn't shipped because that code won't wrk.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? It uses the standard lua DLL.

Comment: Does your code work when written in C?

Comment: Also, more info pls, how does it crash, which compiler did you use, give a complete test program etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the ancient [dlua](http://code.google.com/p/dlua/) bindings, not [LuaD](https://github.com/JakobOvrum/LuaD), which has always had [`luaL_getmetatable`](https://github.com/JakobOvrum/LuaD/blob/master/luad/c/lauxlib.d#L167).

However, both these bindings as well as your code are for Lua 5.1, not 5.2; make sure you link to the correct version of Lua. There is no `lua_open` in Lua 5.2 (and it's deprecated in 5.1).

If you encounter the same problem after linking to the right library, I recommend compiling Lua with the macro `LUA_USE_APICHECK` set and trying again to see exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I was indeed using a wrong version, but only of the dlua head file. I changed them according to their C header equivalents and now everything works!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at the existing Lua-Bindings for D, [LuaD](https://github.com/JakobOvrum/LuaD).

Comment: That's not quite the solution I was looking for. My existing code in C++ is written without LuaD.

Comment: N.B.: LuaD is a lot easier to use cause it's not a simple binding but a very clever wrapper that leverages D's capabilities.